# Java overriding classes in jar for integration testing (with maven)

Tags: java, maven, testing, jar

I have a java maven project in a jar file (bigfat jar, the whole project in one file). I want to do an integration test on it (first option is blackbox testing, but I will settle for whitebox if it is an easier path).

What I am really interested about is the end-to-end result, however some of the interfaces in the middle are APIs and sockets which are hardcoded inside the jar to communicate with a specific port or with a specific website.

What I want to do is to override the classes inside the jar file that are related to these interfaces, and code them with my model interfaces.

The whole new testing project will not go into production, this is purely for testing purposes.

I am using maven.

Any ideas are more than welcome

Comment: don't "override" them, mock them. Mockito might help you get what you need.

Comment: thanks, I am looking at mockito right now, looks interesting. do you think that it is the right way to go in an integration test?

Comment: I came across spock now, which also looks interesting. Does someone have some experience with it? I didn't understand if I can run it with maven